# How to delete event from eventkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is the code in my detail view it can delete event in when u come to detail view press the switch to add event and then press it again to delete it. However, when u come to detail view and then press back (using navigation) and then come o the same page again it cannot delete the event please help

there are more function but I delete just focus on Switch and EVENTKIT

```
//
//  DetailScheduleViewController.m
//  Register
//
//  Created by junejubu on 3/10/2558 BE.
//  Copyright (c) 2558 Thananont Aunsiripant. All rights reserved.
//



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //NSLog(@"check show id sch ::%@",self.Show_ID);

        self.Switch.on = NO;
        self.lblNotification.text = @"Notification OFF";


    [self getUserNotification];
    [self getUserFollow];





}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)getUserNotification
{
    NSString *urlStr2 = @"http://ptvshowthai.com/getNotification.php";
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr2];

    self.getnoti = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    self.getnoti.requestMethod = @"POST";  //DELETE, PUT
    self.getnoti.delegate = self;
    self.getnoti.timeOutSeconds = 30;

    [self.getnoti setPostValue: self.FK_User_ID forKey:@"sMemberID"];

    [self.getnoti setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    [self.getnoti startAsynchronous];

}








- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"requestFinished");

    if (request == self.getnoti) {
        self.dictnoti = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

        self.NOTI = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dataDic in self.dictnoti )
        {
            //            unsigned long count2 = [self.dict2 count];
            NSString *ShowID2 = [dataDic objectForKey:@"Show_ID"];
            self.str2 = [dataDic objectForKey:@"Event_Store"];

          //  NSLog(@"check str2 :: %@",self.str2);


            [self.NOTI addObject:ShowID2];

        }
        NSLog(@"Show who noti ::%@",self.NOTI);
     //   NSLog(@"check str2 :: %@",self.str2);

    }

    if(request ==self.getFollow){

        self.dict2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

        NSLog(@"Dict getFollow :: %@",self.dict2);
        //unsigned long count2 = [self.dict2 count];
        //NSLog(@"show count ::%lu",count2);

        _Show = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //       NSDictionary *dict;
        for (NSDictionary *dataDic in self.dict2 )
        {
            //            unsigned long count2 = [self.dict2 count];
            NSString *ShowID = [dataDic objectForKey:@"Show_ID"];

            [self.Show addObject:ShowID];

        }

        if ([self.Show containsObject: self.Show_ID]) {

            _lblFollow.text = @"Following";
            _lblFollow.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            _i = @"0";
            NSLog(@"check i green :: %@",_i);


            self.Switch.hidden = NO;

            NSLog(@"check self.noti : %@",self.NOTI);

            if ([self.NOTI containsObject: self.Show_ID]){
            self.Switch.on = YES;
            }


            self.lblNotification.hidden = NO;
             [self.Switch addTarget:self action:@selector(Onoff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


        }
        else{

            _lblFollow.text = @"Follow";
            _lblFollow.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            _i = @"1";
            NSLog(@"check i red :: %@",_i);
            self.Switch.hidden = YES;
            self.Switch.on = NO;
            self.lblNotification.hidden = YES;
            [self.Switch addTarget:self action:@selector(Onoff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }

    }
}






-(void)addevent{
    _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];


    if ([_eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        [_eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted){
                addEventgranted = 1;
                EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:_eventStore];
                [event setTitle:self.showNameTitle];
                [event setStartDate: self.today];
                [event setEndDate:[[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:self.duration sinceDate:event.startDate]];
                NSTimeInterval alarmOffset = -300;
                EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];
                [event addAlarm:alarm];

                [event setCalendar:[_eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                NSError *err;
                [_eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
                self.str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"check self.str :: %@",self.str);

                NSString *url = @"http://ptvshowthai.com/insertNotification.php";
                NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

                self.formData = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urls];
                self.formData.requestMethod = @"POST";
                self.formData.delegate = self;
                self.formData.timeOutSeconds = 30;

                [self.formData setPostValue: self.FK_User_ID forKey:@"sMemberID"];
                [self.formData setPostValue: self.Show_ID forKey:@"showID"];
                NSLog(@"check str::: %@",self.str);
                [self.formData setPostValue: self.str forKey:@"event"];

                [self.formData setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
                [self.formData startAsynchronous];

                _lblFollow.text = @"Following";
                _lblFollow.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                NSLog(@"Follow");

                   [self getUserNotification];
            }


        }];
    }
}




-(void)alert
{
    if (addEventgranted == 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Event Successfully added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


-(void)Onoff
{
    if (self.Switch.on) {

        [self addevent];

        [self performSelector:@selector(alert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];


        self.lblNotification.text =@"Notification On";




    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"check str22::%@",self.str2);
        EKEvent* event2 = [_eventStore eventWithIdentifier:self.str2];
        if (event2 != nil) {
            NSError* error = nil;
            [_eventStore removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        }
        self.lblNotification.text =@"Notification OFF";

        NSString *url = @"http://ptvshowthai.com/deleteNotification.php";
        NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

        self.formData = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urls];
        self.formData.requestMethod = @"POST";
        self.formData.delegate = self;
        self.formData.timeOutSeconds = 30;

        [self.formData setPostValue: self.FK_User_ID forKey:@"sMemberID"];
        [self.formData setPostValue: self.Show_ID forKey:@"showID"];

        [self.formData setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
        [self.formData startAsynchronous];

        _lblFollow.text = @"Following";
        _lblFollow.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        NSLog(@"Follow");

           [self getUserNotification];

    }
}
```

Comment: Check that EventStore is getting nil or not..If that is the case alloc eventStore at viewWillAppear..!

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code at switch off condition also

Its better to add below line at ViewDidLoad instead of addEvent method..

```
 _eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Hope it fixes..!

Comment: Happy Coding...Accept it as answer( click on check mark) if works..!